# Images uploaded through ActiveStorage disappear after Dokku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage, dokku

I successfully deployed my Rails application to my DigitalOcean droplet through Dokku. After deploying it, I started uploading images to my site. After pushing a new version and redeploying the app, the uploaded images disappeared.

Now, I've already read that Dokku uses ephemeral storage. I've tried following a guide to make it persistent storage, but with no success.

This is the command that I tried:

```
dokku storage:mount underlords /var/lib/dokku/data/storage:/storage
```

After redeployment, it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using persistent storage, note that the second path is an absolute path *within* your app container. It is not relative to the `/app` directory, but relative to the root path. This means that you should be saving your files to `/storage` and not `/app/storage`.